# How to list specific part of array using SimpleXML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, simplexml

So I have this XML file and I need to list only sites specific to each region.

```html
<xls2cli>
   <Region id="Region1">
      <site>Site1</site>
      <site>Site2</site>
   </Region>
   <Region id="Region2">
      <site>Site3</site>
      <site>Site4</site>
      <site>Site5</site>
      <site>Site6</site>
   </Region>
   <Region id="Region3">
      <site>Site 7</site>
   </Region>
</xls2cli>
```

I am able to list all the sites but no matter what I try, I cant get it to list only sites specific to each region. Im looking to do it a way where I can have something like `Region['Region1']->site`  but obviously that doesnt work. Is there way to do this without using indexes?

```php
foreach ($xls2cli->Region as $Region){
            echo $Region[id]."<br>";
                foreach ($Region->site as $site){
                    echo $site."<br>"; }    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML doesn't know that `id` is anything special, it's just part of the data. The simplest approach is just a boring old `if` statement in your existing loop:

```
foreach ($xls2cli->Region as $Region){
    if( $Region['id'] == 'Region1' ) {
        echo $Region['id']."<br>";
        foreach ($Region->site as $site){
           echo $site."<br>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use [the `xpath()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), which can do queries based on the content of the XML:

```
foreach ( $xls2cli->xpath('./Region[@id="Region1"]') as $Region ) {
    echo $Region['id']."<br>";
    foreach ($Region->site as $site){
        echo $site."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: First method works perfectly and its what I was looking for thanks! Using xpath doesnt display anything for me though. Is it because I use " $xls2cli = simplexml_load_file("/var/www/html/uploads/".$filename); " ? I also tried xpath before and kept getting " Array {0} " outputs.

Comment: @blitz94 Nope, it's because I'm not very good at XPath :P The expression should be `./Region[@id="Region1"]`